# Set a value to list a datatype after checking values of other datatypes

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-clause, lookup

I have a list that holds session data for a user. After I update information that is held within the session data, I need to set the session data to this new information. Trying to do a LINQ query that's like so, user is the global session data and that holds individual which is the List. So I need to lookup in the list where address and city equal this and once found I need to set the state equal to this and their is only going to be one record in the list that will match it.

```
user.Individual = user.Individual.Where(a => a.address == "ABC" && a.city == "MIAMI").ToList()
```

So above I'm able to look through the list to find where the address and city equals something. How do I set `a.State=="FL"` based on that `Where`, and if those two are true/found in the list.

Comment: Do you want to to set `State` property to all elements in the resulting list?

Comment: no just state to where the address and city equals that

Comment: If you are looking for individuals that have address "ABC" and are from "MIAMI" in "FL", why not just add `&& s.State == "FL"` into the "Where" condition?

Comment: becuase s.state does not equal FL I want to set s.state ==  FL

Comment: == is used for comparison, not assignment. Judging by the answer you selected, you DO want to set `State` property to "FL" for elements in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (this assumes you have one person matching your where clause):

```
//get the user
var idividual = user.Individual.SingleOrDefault(a => a.address == "ABC" && a.city == "MIAMI");

if(idividual != null)
{
   idividual.State = "FL";

   //persist user in DB or elsewhere
}
```

If you have more than 1 item in the resulting set, do this:

```
//get the user
var idividuals = user.Individual.Where(a => a.address == "ABC" && a.city == "MIAMI").ToList();

individuals.ForEach(i=>i.State="FL");
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add the && to the where agian ?

```
user.Individual = user.Individual.Where(a => (a.address == "ABC" && a.city == "MIAMI") && a.State=="FL").ToList()
```

Edit what do you mean with set?